# Address of each character of std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-address

I tried to print the address of each character of `std::string`. But I amn't understanding what is happening internally with `std::string` that is resulting this output while for the array it is giving the address as I expected. Could someone please explain what is going on?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   string str = "Hello";
   int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

   for( int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i )
      cout << &str[i] << endl;

   cout << "**************" << endl;

   for( int i=0; i<5; ++i )
      cout << &a[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
ello
llo
lo
o
**************
0x7fff5fbff950
0x7fff5fbff954
0x7fff5fbff958
0x7fff5fbff95c
0x7fff5fbff960
```

Comment: The first tries to print a `char*`, which means it'll try to print a C-style string (until it hits `\0` or touches an address it shouldn't have). The second thing you're doing is just running through an array of `int` and printing the address `int*`. Also be careful not to use the former in real code, because `std::string` is not guaranteed to be `NULL`-terminated.

Comment: The difference here is not caused by std::string, but caused by the different output logic between `char*` and `int*` for std::ostream.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When a `std::ostream` tries to print a `char*` it assumes it's a C-style string.

Cast it to a `void*` before printing and you will get what you expect:

```
cout << (void*) &str[i] << endl;
```

Comment: `void` means it has no type? And then `cout` uses the memory address?

Comment: We use `void*` (note the `*`: it's a pointer) to "forget" that it's a `char*`. If `cout` sees a `char*` then it will try to print it as a C-style string (ie. an array of `char`s up until the next null byte). If `cout` sees a `void*`, though, it will print the address that it points to.

Answer (score 1):

or you may use the old printf

```
printf("\n%x",&s[i]);
```